# Use purrr to get quantile of corresponding matrix entries in a list

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have the following `reprex` list of 10 sample matrices:

```r
# Sample of 10 3*3 matrices
z1 <- matrix(101:104, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z2 <- matrix(201:204, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z3 <- matrix(301:304, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z4 <- matrix(401:404, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z5 <- matrix(501:504, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z6 <- matrix(601:604, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z7 <- matrix(701:704, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z8 <- matrix(801:804, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z9 <- matrix(901:904, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z10 <- matrix(1001:1004, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

# Combine all matrices into a single list
za <- list(z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7, z8, z9, z10)
```

What we would like is to take `za` as an input and obtain `2 2*2 matrices` called an `upper_quantile` and `lower_quantile` matrices.

Essentially this is to take the above list of 10 matrices and take the upper 97.5% quantile for the **corresponding entries**. And the same for the lower 2.5% quantile.

In this case we can **manually** construct the `upper_quantile` matrix for this example as follows:

```r
upper_quantile <- matrix(data = c(quantile(x = seq(101, 1001, by = 100), probs = 0.975),
                                  c(quantile(x = seq(102, 1002, by = 100), probs = 0.975)),
                                  c(quantile(x = seq(103, 1003, by = 100), probs = 0.975)),
                                  c(quantile(x = seq(104, 1004, by = 100), probs = 0.975)))
                         , nrow = 2
                         , ncol = 2
                         , byrow = FALSE)

upper_quantile
#>       [,1]  [,2]
#> [1,] 978.5 980.5
#> [2,] 979.5 981.5
```

I would like to understand how to do this using `purrr` or `tidyverse` tools as I have been trying to avoid cumbersome loops on lists and would like to adjust to dimensions automatically.

Could anyone please assist?

Comment: I didn't see where `za` was used in your `upper_quantile` code.

Comment: @Tung - it wasn't. I was showing a manual way of doing something that I would like using `za` and `purrr` so that the output could be checked in this case

Comment: Not a `purr` answer, so I'll just put it in a comment - `apply(simplify2array(za), 1:2, quantile, probs=0.975)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly clunky method which at least keeps everything in one pipe. It assumes that all the matrices are the same dimension, which needs to be true else the desired output doesn't make much sense. Working with matrices in `purrr` is always a little odd. The approach is basically to use `flatten` to make it easy to group the cells in the order we want, which is one column per location. That lets us map across columns to produce another vector, and then put that vector back into the right matrix. Might need some testing for larger matrices than 2x2.

The other approach I thought about was using `cross` to make a list of all index combinations, and then mapping through and creating the matrix cell by cell analogous to your example. Can attempt that if desired.

```r
library(tidyverse)
z1 <- matrix(101:104, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z2 <- matrix(201:204, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z3 <- matrix(301:304, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z4 <- matrix(401:404, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z5 <- matrix(501:504, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z6 <- matrix(601:604, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z7 <- matrix(701:704, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z8 <- matrix(801:804, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z9 <- matrix(901:904, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
z10 <- matrix(1001:1004, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

# Combine all matrices into a single list
za <- list(z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7, z8, z9, z10)

quant_mat <- function(list, p){
  dim = ncol(list[[1]]) * nrow(list[[1]])
  list %>%
    flatten_int() %>%
    matrix(ncol = dim, byrow = TRUE) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    map_dbl(quantile, probs = p) %>%
    matrix(ncol = ncol(list[[1]]))
}

quant_mat(za, 0.975)
#>       [,1]  [,2]
#> [1,] 978.5 980.5
#> [2,] 979.5 981.5
quant_mat(za, 0.025)
#>       [,1]  [,2]
#> [1,] 123.5 125.5
#> [2,] 124.5 126.5
```

Created on 2018-03-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you - I did more testing. The `flatten_int()` needs to be changed to `flatten_dbl()` to apply to other settings. I need to do more efficiency testing (on larger matrices as you mentioned). But I will accept this answer and post back if I have further queries.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for a single quantile using tidyverse:

```
tibble(za) %>%
  mutate(za = map(za, ~ data.frame(t(flatten_dbl(list(.)))))) %>%
  unnest(za) %>%
  summarize_all(quantile, probs = .975) %>%
  matrix(ncol = 2)
```